# how the paginated report export to csv format

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

How to export paginated report as CSV.How to export report using API with passing parameters.
In frontend click the export button, then the Paginated report export as CSV

POST [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportId}/ExportTo](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/%7BreportId%7D/ExportTo)

I use this but got error...What is the correct format to export the report and give me sample of post call
I need a API function to export a report!.